# TFS Customized security groups at collection level

Tags: tfs, permissions, azure-devops, user-permissions, tfs-security

We have group of developers, Testers & BA's who will work for more that 30 projects under collection, so instead of adding them for each project want to create security groups at collection level so everyone will have access to all the projects under collection.
On TFS, we want to have customized groups like Developers, Testers, BA's  at collection level so they will have access to all the projects so that I don't need to add them for each project.

So instead of adding them for each project want to create security groups at collection level so everyone will have access to all the projects under collection? So how can I do that!!!

Comment: Okay. You've provided a requirement. What is your question?

Comment: I had updated the request

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the new customized groups as members of the "Project Collection Administrators" group. This will grant access to all projects in the collection, including the futures ones.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I will try that and also can you share what are permissions to be enabled for Developers, Testers , BA groups.

Comment: Hugh - I had created customized group and added it to Project Collection Administrators and also deny all the permissions except Create workspace , View instance information & View build resources for developers but when I looked at the project level they have more than required permissions like Delete repository, create repository,manage permissions. Is there anyway to deny those permissions at the collection level , so in simple I want to have permissions for developers like to contribute the code, work items and view build definitions and also same with QA

Comment: For your demand ,I am afraid it is not feasible in the collection-level permission.Like repo is only for projects, so you need to set it  in project settings. Specific permissions need to be set  in specific places, not all in collection-level.

Comment: Thanks for responding Hugh, Even I was thinking of doing that way too